# What is the most elegant way to load multiple variables asynchronously in parallel in c#

Tags: c#, async-await

This is best illustrated with an example.

Say I want to load several records from a database at the beginning of a web request. I want to pull in all the necessary data asynchronously. I
 might have something like this:

```
var user = await Database.GetUser(userId);
var group = await Database.GetGroup(groupId);
var members = await Database.GetGroupMembers(groupId);
```

Now let’s say I want to load this data in parallel. Suddenly this nice clear/clean async code becomes a bit messy.

```
var userTask = Database.GetUser(userId);
var groupTask = Database.GetGroup(groupId);
var membersTask = Database.GetGroupMembers(groupId);

await Task.WhenAll(userTask, groupTask, membersTask);

var user = userTask.Result;
var group = groupTask.Result;
var members = membersTask.Result;
```

Is there a nicer, more succinct way to achieve this?

Comment: It doesn't look messy, imho. You can remove `Task.WhenAll`, but it worsens readability even more. Now it is read easily: "make 3 requests, wait them all, and then get results".

Comment: Well, if you add one task you have to modify 3 places, and one is especially not very visible. I applaud OP in the effort.

Comment: not particularly messy. the async framework does a good job hiding all of the complex synchronization. pay attention if there is no hidden serialization in the database layer. do you open a new connection in either data retrieval function? does it pay off if you compare it with a sequential approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Separate the task start and the `await`:

```
var userTask = Database.GetUser(userId);
var groupTask = Database.GetGroup(groupId);
var membersTask = Database.GetGroupMembers(groupId);

var user = await userTask;
var group = await groupTask;
var members = await membersTask;
```

Comment: This is also beneficial in that `.Result` is generally not used in favour of `await`.

Comment: It's fine for the current example, but if the below execution involved updating the UI, you might end up with a UI that e.g. has already loaded the user but not the group. The OP's version would only load the data in the UI when all tasks are done, thus never showing "half" of the UI. Neither option is wrong, I'm just trying to point out the difference.

Comment: @Flater: The solution here specifically involves awaiting and assigning every result to variables before continuing. Kind of repetitive if you were immediately going to update a property, but avoids that issue, I think?

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. If I name the task variables getUser, getGroup and getMembers respectively it reads well.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the code looks fine except it [should use `await` instead of `Result`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html) (for nicer error handling semantics).

```
var userTask = Database.GetUser(userId);
var groupTask = Database.GetGroup(groupId);
var membersTask = Database.GetGroupMembers(groupId);

await Task.WhenAll(userTask, groupTask, membersTask);

var user = await userTask;
var group = await groupTask;
var members = await membersTask;
```

However, it can be made a little nicer now that tuples are out. This week I've been [playing around with a tuple-based `WhenAll`](https://github.com/StephenClearyApps/DotNetApis/blob/master/service/DotNetApis.Common/AsyncTupleHelpers.cs). Defining it is a pain right now (a reflection-based approach would be more dynamic):

```
public static class AsyncTupleHelpers
{
  public static async Task<(T1, T2)> WhenAll<T1, T2>(Task<T1> task1, Task<T2> task2) =>
      (await task1.ConfigureAwait(false), await task2.ConfigureAwait(false));
  public static async Task<(T1, T2, T3)> WhenAll<T1, T2, T3>(Task<T1> task1, Task<T2> task2, Task<T3> task3) =>
      (await task1.ConfigureAwait(false), await task2.ConfigureAwait(false), await task3.ConfigureAwait(false));
  /* More if you want, following the same pattern */
}
```

But once defined, it can be used as such:

```
var (user, group, members) = await AsyncTupleHelpers.WhenAll(
    Database.GetUser(userId),
    Database.GetGroup(groupId),
    Database.GetGroupMembers(groupId));
```

No separate tasks needed.

**Update**:

> I didn't mention it in the original example but I raise an exception in the event that a record isn't found.

In that case, you can use local methods, as such:

```
async Task<User> GetUser(T userId) => await Database.GetUser(userId) ?? throw new Exception("User not found.");
async Task<Group> GetGroup(T groupId) => await Database.GetGroup(groupId) ?? throw new Exception("Group not found.");
var (user, group, members) = await AsyncTupleHelpers.WhenAll(
    GetUser(userId),
    GetGroup(groupId),
    Database.GetGroupMembers(groupId));
```

Comment: That is certainly an... _interesting_ use of C#'s language-level tuple support.

Comment: I'll take that as a compliment. :D  It is a bit unusual in that it's really treating "tuples" as a collection of items, while allowing those items to be *different* types and preserving that type safety.

Comment: It's not really unusual considering they implemented this feature in a way that _encourages_ you to use tuples as bags of named, arbitrarily typed values.  It seems to me that people wanted a simple syntax for structural 'record' types, but for some reason the answer was "hell yeah, tuples everywhere".  *\*shrug\**